# Can you ask if an action has been completed after "Are you done"?

Tags: sentence-construction

For example, is it right to ask, "Are you done using the pen?" or "Are you done chopping onions?" ?

Comment: Yes, you can. "Are you done . . .?" is commonly used to confirm whether an action has been completed or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can say that. Although it would sound slightly out of place in formal speech or writing. Alternatives include:

> Are you **done with** the pen?
>   Are you **finished with** the pen?
>   Are you **finished using** the pen?
>   Have you **finished using** the pen?
>
> Are you **finished** chopping onions?
>   Have you **finished** chopping onions?

Any alternative using *finished* will be more acceptable in formal speech than a sentence using *done*.